# Google Prettify Removes Line Breaks?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pretty-print

When I try to use Google Prettify to syntax highlight my code, I notice that it causes code to become one line ... why is that? When I remvoe prettify, it works

Comment: Out of curiosity (and if you still remember/know), did you apply the prettyprint class to a pre or code tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well-known issue that someone's still trying to track down. Hang on, I've got the bug favourited somewhere...

Yeah, [there we go, here's the link to the issue in the Google Code issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=127), assuming you're using IE, or one of the other affected browser/versions.

Comment: Only in IE10 any more... this is the newest NuGet package to date

Comment: For me, using <pre class="prettyprint"> rather than <code class="prettyprint"> worked :D.