# code inside pre goes in one line on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, pre

I'm trying to take the value from a `textarea` and put it inside a `pre tag`, and it works ok on chrome and mozilla but on IE8 the entire content stays on one line in the `pre tag`

jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/uwunug/4/edit

this is the whole thing:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){

$('#b1').click(function(){
x = $('textarea').val();
$('#tt').html(htmlEscape(x));    
});

});
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')            
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
</script>


 <textarea cols='50' rows='20'>
 </textarea>
 <button id='b1'>make code</button>
 <pre class="prettyprint" id='tt'>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

I noticed (by replacing `\n` to 'enter') the `\n` chars go into the pre but they don't produce new line in there

Comment: I notice you're marking your "pre" with "prettyprint" -- does that mean you might be (a) using Google Prettify, and therefore (b) running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830408/google-prettify-removes-line-breaks)? (I can't tell, because your code doesn't work at all for me on IE8 from jsbin...)

Comment: @Matt Gibson yes, but atm I removed the prettypring css and js in order to focus just on this issue, have just found a solution btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "IE applies HTML normalization to the data that is assigned to the innerHTML property. This causes incorrect display of whitespace in elements that ought to preserve formatting, such as `<pre>` and `<textarea>`."

[Inserting a newline into a pre tag (IE, Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195363/inserting-a-newline-into-a-pre-tag-ie-javascript)

The `\n` solution is probably going to be your best shot (the only other option is to use innerText it seems, but I prefer your solution).

Answer (score 4):

atm my solution is to add this line at the end:

```
.replace(/\n/g, '<br\>')
```

in my htmlEscape, so it's like this:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')         
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')                      
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\n/g, '<br\>');
}
```

please post your answer if you know a better one

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I had completly same htmlEscape function and used prettyPrint an it worked on Chrome and FF but your line made it work on IE8 too!(amazing), however I found out that IE or htmlEscape or Prettyprint eats reagular spaces away so I just added one line after yours: `.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');`. So far so good!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is IE using innerHTML, then don't use innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("tt").appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
```

instead of

```
$('#tt').html(htmlEscape(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById("ID").textContent = 'YOUR TEXT';
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the `<pre>` element is to display all white space, including line feeds, so by default you should be seeing new lines where you have `\n` characters.

If you're not seeing that, then it implies that the default behaviour of the element has been overridden by your stylesheets.

This is done using the CSS `white-space` property. By default the `<pre>` tag has this property set to `white-space:pre;`. Setting the `white-space` property like this will cause the `<pre>` element - or indeed any other element - to display all white space, including line feeds, as per the default for the `<pre>` element.

There are a number of possible settings for the `white-space` property. You can find examples of them all and how they affect the layout here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/

So if you want the `<pre>` to act as normal, you should either remove the styles which are currently setting the `white-space` property, or override them and set it back to the default value.

Hope that helps.

ps - if you plan to try out the various values for `white-space` as listed on the page I linked above, please note that older versions of IE (IE7 and earlier) may not support all possible options for this property. If you're worried about this, then [QuirksMode.org has a compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) which may help you.

Comment: I have zero stylesheets included, so that's not the case

Comment: hmm, in that case, there's no good reason for `<pre>` to show in any format other than the default. Have you checked the Developer Tools (F12) to see what styles are actually being applied? There might be something you've missed.

Comment: it's nothing there and I tried setting style="white-pace:pre;" and that didn't changed anything

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
                 replace('\r','&lt;br/&gt;')                               .
```