# Why is the Syntax Highlighter not rendering vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

Well I have no knowledge of this syntax highlighter thingy but somehow I managed to put forward the syntax highlighter script into one of my blogs using prettify code. But somehow the code instead of showing up completely in a vertical line shows up as a single line with full code. Here is the code I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.geniusknight.weebly.com/files/theme/prettify.css"/>
<pre class="prettyprint">
&lt;!--Responsive Ads on Non responsive sites code starts--&gt;
&lt;div id="google-ads-1"&gt;&lt;/div&gt; 
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;  
    /* Replace ca-pub-XXX with your AdSense Publisher ID */ 
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXX";

    /* Replace YYY with the AdSense Ad Slot ID */ 
    google_ad_slot = "YYY";

    /* Replace ZZZ with the custom height of your Ad Unit */
    google_ad_height = "ZZZ";

    ad = document.getElementById('google-ads-1');

    if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        google_ad_width = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;  
    } else {
        google_ad_width = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
    } 

    if (google_ad_width>1200) {        
        google_ad_width = 1200;
    }  else if (google_ad_width<120) {
        google_ad_width = 120;
    }  

    if (google_ad_height>1200) {        
        google_ad_height = 1200;
    }  else if (google_ad_height<50) {
        google_ad_height = 50;
    }  

    if ((google_ad_width>300) && (google_ad_height>300)) {        
        google_ad_height = 300;
    }  

    document.write (
     '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:' 
      + google_ad_width + 'px;height:' 
      + google_ad_height + 'px" data-ad-client="' 
      + google_ad_client + '" data-ad-slot="' 
      + google_ad_slot + '"></ins>'
    );  
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); 
&lt;/script&gt;
 &lt;script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;!--tutorial at geniusknight.weebly.com --&gt;
</pre>
<script src="http://www.geniusknight.weebly.com/files/theme/prettify.js"></script>
<script>prettyPrint();</script>
```

I used it here in this article http://geniusknight.weebly.com/6/post/2014/01/how-to-display-responsive-adsense-ads-on-non-responsive-sites.html . Am I doing something wrong here or is it that I am missing some parameter or is it something to do with weebly, also in the head I put the prettify css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.geniusknight.weebly.com/files/theme/prettify.css" />
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Old versions had a rendering bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830408/google-prettify-removes-line-breaks

Comment: Oh I see! Can you please redirect me to the latest version. Please! :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: BUT I believe the real problem is your PRE has no line breaks in it....

Comment: OOooh ! How do I do that. Use </br> tag or something else

Answer (score 0):

Well got it fixed using css in the pre tag using whitespaces

```
<pre style="width:95%;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="prettyprint">
```